# How to implement a time lock before submitting a new response in Google Forms

Tags: forms, timer, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm a TL of an outsourcing company. We deal with alot of entries. We usually track progress via Google spreadsheet that tracks their updates using a timestamp script but recently we are having problems with real time updating. Employees, instead of updating entries in real-time, tend to load, for example, 10 entries and update their status later in one sweep; which is kind of messing the management's Production per hour report.

Now I figure Google Forms might do the job because

1. They will not have access with the spreadsheet
2. Timestamp can't be edit if they don't have access.
3. They can't change the information once they've clicked SUMBIT.

In researching. Google usually helps, but not when it comes to google forms. So I've resorted to asking here since most of the answers I found when searching for scripts for Google sheets came from here.

**My question is:**
Is it possible to set a sort of "response lock period", meaning a form won't be accepting responses for a certain period once the current response has been submitted?
Example:
Bruce successfully entered a response at 12:00 AM
Form is no longer accepting responses until 12:10 AM
It is now 12:10 AM, the form is now accepting responses from Bruce.
It doesn't really have to specify a person for the lock to be implemented but if you can manage, that would be a great help. I figured the form's auto timestamp on the linked spreadsheet might be the key to it.

Answer (score 0):

People are playing the system because the system needs to be played in order for them to work.

Your suggestion, time-locking, will only trigger different gaming behavior. Why not get rid of the real problem: the management's Production per hour report?

Comment: This goes in a comment as is not an answer

Comment: We want them to stop working. To do more than what is required per hour would let the upper management increase the minimum quota to match the high performer. Some entries takes a long time to finish, some quick so it's not impossible for one employee to reach the quota*2. That would be great for that one or two employees but for the rest having trouble with their entries, that would not be cool if their quota was doubled. It would not be cool for me too if the high performers stopped working the rest of the afternoon because they've already reached the quota.

Comment: Why don't you filter out the high performers? Or do some sizing so you can correct the stuff or use SPC to see what the natural behavior of the process/system is and if the targets set by management are good or need to be revised. A better distribution of work also might do the trick: high performers get the more difficult jobs.

Comment: We are an outsourcing company. Our client sees nothing but numbers. Obviously, we can't tell them how many we can do when the numbers say differently. So revision is based on performance. What revision our clients want based on the numbers is cut off 40% of the employees, keep the best, increase the quota; which you can imagine, we do not want. All are hard working employees. Some just takes more time than others and all do manage the keep the current quota. About distribution of work, it's only when the employee start processing entries does it become apparent if it is easy to do or not.

Comment: I hear what you say. Have you tried normalizing the data entries? When it is known at the time of entry if the work was easy, medium or heavy, then your client will understand that could do more than others.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.
You can enable/disable responses but for all, not for individual users.
Just let them enter whatever, and make a report to determine who submits at the wrong times. Its still much better than your previous solution. You could also validate onFormSubmit, mark it invalid and email the user telling them the entry was invalid so they submit again.

Comment: Can you give me an example for the "for all"? I understand it would be impossible without a google apps account. I actually want my employees to stop working once we reach a certain per hour quota, that would be much better than having the some employees reach the day quota in the morning and slack off in the afternoon which would get the lower Management (me) some heat from the Upper management.

Answer (score 0):

Zig is right, forms can not be user dependent (for accepting responses) but you could get that behavior using a form build with UiApp or HTML Service.

Depending on how complex your form would be it can be very simple or pretty hard but it is definitely doable.

You will need a way to identify the user either manually (users entering their ID) or automatically (if you have a Google Apps account that will be easy as well) and store every user email or ID somewhere (script properties or user properties or scriptDb...) so that the script will be able to decide wether the form (the UI) shows up or not for that user at that time... this part will be easy !

Comment: Just a two page form. 2 drop down.(Employee name and status), text box for the entries and an optional paragraph box for comments depending on the status.